# How to remove specific element from a list of list in java?

Tags: java, list, loops, arraylist

I removed specific element from list of list using for loop and making deepCopy. Is there any other way to remove specific element from List of List?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
         List<ArrayList<String>> listA = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        list1.add("cucumber");
        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        list2.add("carrot");
        ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        list3.add("spinach");
        ArrayList<String> list4 = new ArrayList<String>();
        list4.add("kale");
        listA.add(list1);
        listA.add(list2);
        listA.add(list3);
        listA.add(list4);
        System.out.println("Original-->"+listA);

        List<List<String>> deepCopyOfListA = new ArrayList<List<String>>(listA);
        System.out.println("Deepcopy -->"+deepCopyOfListA);

        for (List<String> item : deepCopyOfListA) {
            if (item.contains("kale") || item.contains("cucumber")){
            listA.remove(item);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Final-->"+listA);
    }
}
```

From the answers below, this seemed the most convenient. 
Using Iterator to remove the desired elements with if condition. Tested and it works great. Thanks everyone for your input.

```
Iterator<ArrayList<String>> itr = listA.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        List<String> item = itr.next();
        if ((item.contains("cucumber") || item.contains("kale"))) {
            itr.remove();
        }
```

Comment: you are removing the whole list, not just the element

Comment: you're not making a shallow copy, not a deep copy - is this your actual code? what is the problem here?

Comment: your variable `DeepCopyOfListA` doesn't exist, maybe you mean `deepCopyOfListA`? ost the actual code you use

Comment: The way you have done it, from the outer list, a complete inner list will be removed if it has the string `cucumber`. Is this what you want to do or you want to remove just the string, `cucumber` from the inner lists?

Comment: I have edited the code to match it to what i have worked on. Seems my previous code didn't make my question clear enough. Hopefully this edit will make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear whether you want to remove the complete inner list (i.e. `item`) if it has the string, `cucumber` -OR- you want to remove just the string, `cucumber` from the inner lists (i.e. `item`s). Given below are solutions for each of these scenarios.

**To remove the complete inner list (i.e. `item`) if it has the string `cucumber`:**

```
public void removeSpecificElement(Response response) {
    List<List<String>> listA = response.path("response.A");
    Iterator<List<String>> itr = listA.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        List<String> item = itr.next();
        if (item.contains("cucumber")) {
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

**To remove just the string, `cucumber` from the inner list (i.e. `item`):**

```
public void RremoveSpecificElement(Response response) {
    List<List<String>> listA = response.path("response.A");
    for (List<String> item : listA) {
        item.removeAll(Collections.singleton("cucumber"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to remove the inner list which had string cucumber. Using iterator is a good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As of [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), if you want to remove a certain element from the inner list, you have to first iterate the outer one and then use [`List::removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) to the inner one:

```
// Mutates the original list
List<List<String>> outerList = ...            
for (List<String> innerList : outerList) {
    innerList.removeIf(item -> "cucumber".equals(item));
}

// Creates a new one while keeping the original untouched
List<List<String>> newList = outerList.stream()
    .map(innerList -> innerList.stream()
        .filter(item -> !"cucumber".equals(item))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For the lower versions than 8, you should use a proper removal way using `Iterator`:

```
for (final List<String> innerList: outerList) {
    Iterator<String> iterator = innerList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        if ("cucumber".equals(item)) {
            iterator .remove();
        }
    }
}
```

---

In any case, use `"cucumber".equals(item)` rather than `item.equals("cucumber")` because the former one is null-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove "cucumber" from the list of lists just by iterating the list. No need to create explicit iterator objects, no need to use the weird "stream" syntax. No need to create a copy either - deep or shallow. Of course, you may want to create a copy anyway, so that you still have the original values - but that's up to you.

```
List<List<String>> ListA=response.path("response.A");
for (List<String> item : ListA) {
    item.remove("cucumber");
}
```

Note that if any of the lists happen to contain more than one cucumber, this will remove only the first one.

Comment: I cannot remove the element from the same list while iterating through it. I get error "java.util.ConcurrentModificationException". That's why I had to create a deepcopy of the original list.

Comment: With the code snippet in the answer, you are not removing elements from the list `ListA` while you iterate through it. You are calling a method on a single element in that list.

Answer (score 0):

```
DeepCopyOfListA.removeAll(
        ListA.stream()
        .filter(innerList -> innerList.stream()
           .anyMatch(str -> str.contains("cucumber")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```

Also want to attract your attention, that according to Java Code Convention you should name your variables with lowercase (camel case, in fact). So, listA and deepCopyofListA.

Comment: This is wrong. It removes the whole list if the "cucumber" is present, not only that item.

Comment: Yup. I had typo error before. Otherwise my variables were in camel case.